# Net maui display alert view model error

Tags: c#, maui

como estan? estoy desarrollando una app en .NET Maui con MVVM , el problema que tengo es cuando invoco al metodo "await DisplayAlert()".

Anteriormente, en mis viewModel ya llamo varias veces al metodo "await DisplayAlert()" y me funciona bien, pero en este caso, estoy llamando a un RelayCommand desde el CodeBehind de mi View(Page), y a la hora de invocarlo y llegar a la linea de codigo que ejecuta el "await DisplayAlert()" Me tira el siguiente error:

'exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Les dejo mi codigo:

ScanBarcodeProduct.xaml

En esta vista, se desata el evento que se ejecuta cuando el escaner detecta el codigo de barra. El evento es el siguiente: BarcodesDetected="barCodeReader_BarcodesDetected"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Views.Products.ScanBarcodeProductPage"
             xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;assembly=ZXing.Net.Maui"
             xmlns:dxc="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Controls;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Controls"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Helpers"
             Title="ScanBarcodeProductPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="SeparatorStyle" TargetType="BoxView">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#EBEBEB"/>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="1"/>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="DragDropTemplateStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
                <Setter Property="Padding">
                    <x:OnIdiom Phone="0,0,0,0" Tablet="60,0,0,0"/>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#56585c"/>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="dxc:SimpleButton">
                <Setter Property="IconColor" Value="#404144"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#404144"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="24,8"/>
                <Setter Property="IconIndent" Value="16"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Start"/>
                <Setter Property="PressedBackgroundColor" Value="#e8e8e8"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Fill"/>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="urgentItemTemplate">
                <StackLayout Margin="0" Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="#ffedcc">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource DragDropTemplateStyle}" Text="Text" TextColor="#e59601"/>
                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
                <StackLayout Margin="0" Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource DragDropTemplateStyle}" Text="Text"/>
                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="strikethroughItemTemplate">
                <StackLayout Margin="0" Spacing="0">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource DragDropTemplateStyle}" Text="Text}" TextDecorations="Strikethrough"
                           TextColor="#989898"/>
                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

            <Label Text="Escanear codigo de barras." x:Name="lblOperation" 
                   FontFamily="ComfortaaBold" FontSize="Title" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <dxc:DXPopup IsOpen="{Binding IsOpenPopup}"
                         AllowScrim="True" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Margin="16"
                         CornerRadius="16">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                    <Label Text="{Binding PopupTitle}"
                           TextColor="#404144"
                           Margin="24,16,24,14"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    
                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}" Margin="24,0"/>

                    <dxc:SimpleButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Text="Crear" TextColor="ForestGreen" 
                                      IsVisible="{Binding IsButtonCreateProductVisible}" Command="{Binding ExecuteActionCommand}">
                        <dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>
                            <FontImageSource Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.Plus}" Color="ForestGreen"/>
                        </dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>
                        
                    </dxc:SimpleButton>

                    <dxc:SimpleButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Text="Editar" TextColor="Yellow" 
                                      IsVisible="{Binding IsButtonUpdateProductVisible}" Command="{Binding ExecuteActionCommand}">
                        <dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>
                            <FontImageSource Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.AccountEdit}" Color="Yellow"/>
                        </dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>

                    </dxc:SimpleButton>

                    <dxc:SimpleButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Text="Eliminar" TextColor="#ff5e61" 
                                      IsVisible="{Binding IsButtonDeleteProductVisible}" Command="{Binding ExecuteActionCommand}">
                        <dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>
                            <FontImageSource Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.Delete}" Color="#ff5e61"/>
                        </dxc:SimpleButton.Icon>

                    </dxc:SimpleButton>

                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}" Margin="24,0"/>
                    
                    <dxc:SimpleButton Text="Cancel"
                                      TextColor="#2088ff"
                                      PressedBackgroundColor="#e8e8e8"                        
                                      BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                      Margin="0,0,0,6"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </dxc:DXPopup>

            <zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView 
                HeightRequest="500"
                WidthRequest="500"
                x:Name="barCodeReader" 
                IsDetecting="True" 
                IsTorchOn="False" 
                BarcodesDetected="barCodeReader_BarcodesDetected"
                
            />


        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Una vez que se ejecuta el metodo vamos al .cs de la vista:
ScanBarCodeProduct.xaml.cs

```
using StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewModels.Products;

namespace StoreSysAppDistribuidoras.Views.Products;

public partial class ScanBarcodeProductPage : ContentPage
{

    ScanBarCodeProductViewModel viewModel;
    public ScanBarcodeProductPage(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;
        barCodeReader.Options = new ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeReaderOptions
        {
            Formats = ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeFormat.Ean13,
            AutoRotate = true
        };
    }

    private async void barCodeReader_BarcodesDetected(object sender, ZXing.Net.Maui.BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
    {
        barCodeReader.IsDetecting = false;
        var item = lblOperation.Text.ToString();
        if (e.Results.Any())
        {
            var barCodeReaderResult = e.Results.FirstOrDefault();
            if (barCodeReaderResult != null)
            {
                string barCode = barCodeReaderResult.Value;
                await viewModel.SearchProductByBarCode(barCode.ToString());

                if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.SEARCH_PRODUCT))
                {

                }
                else if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.CREATE_PRODUCT))
                {
                       viewModel.IsButtonCreateProductVisible = true;
                       viewModel.IsOpenPopup = true;
                }
                else if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.UPDATE_PRODUCT))
                {
                       viewModel.IsButtonDeleteProductVisible = true;
                       viewModel.IsButtonUpdateProductVisible = true;
                       viewModel.IsButtonModifyPriceVisible = true;
                       viewModel.IsOpenPopup = true;
                }
                else if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.STOCK_COUNT))
                {
                    if (viewModel.ExecuteActionCommand.CanExecute(null))
                        viewModel.ExecuteActionCommand.Execute(null);

                    /*bool allowModifyStock = true;
                    if(viewModel.ProductFound == null)
                    {
                        allowModifyStock = false;
                        await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () =>
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Producto no encontrado", "Notifique que se debe cargar el producto.","OK");
                            return;
                        });
                    }

                    if (!allowModifyStock) { return; }

                    Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
                    {
                        string result = await Shell.Current.DisplayPromptAsync("Modificar stock", "Ingrese un valor de stock", initialValue: "0", maxLength: 2, keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric);
                        viewModel.ProductFound.UpdateStock(Convert.ToDecimal(result));
                        await viewModel.ExecuteAction();
                    });*/
                }
                else if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.MODIFY_PRICE))
                {
                    bool allowModifyPrice = true;
                    if (viewModel.ProductFound == null)
                    {
                        allowModifyPrice = false;
                        await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () => 
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Producto no encontrado", "Notifique que se debe cargar el producto.", "OK");
                            return;

                        });
                    }
                    if (!allowModifyPrice) { return; }

                    await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        string result = await Shell.Current.DisplayPromptAsync("Modificar precio", "Ingrese un valor", initialValue: "0", maxLength: 2, keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric);
                        viewModel.ProductFound.UpdatePrice(Convert.ToDecimal(result));
                        await viewModel.ExecuteAction();
                    });          
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dentro del .cs, estoy haciendo que caiga en el siguiente condicional:

```
else if (viewModel.ScanOperation.Equals(ScanBarCodeProductViewModel.SCAN_OPERATION.STOCK_COUNT))
```

El cual luego ejecuta el codigo que llama al RelayCommand de mi viewModel, que lo que hace es lo siguiente:

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task ExecuteAction()
{
  
        if(productFoundNullOrNew())
        {
await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Producto no encontrado", "Notifique que se debe cargar el producto.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        var product = await ServiceLocator.GetService<ProductSearcher>().GetByIdAsync(productFound.Id);
}
```

y el problema lo tengo en el momento que se ejecuta la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Producto no encontrado", "Notifique que se debe cargar el producto.", "OK");
```

El error que me arroja como lo habia mencionado anteriormente es el siguiente:

```
'exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
```

Espero haber sido claro y espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: No hay una inner exception con mas informacion???